# Paytm Missing parameters

Tags: ios, swift, paytm

I am working with one iOS app where I have to integrate **Paytm** but I am not able to complete this task with Old SDK (PGSDK_VERSION @"2.1"). It's working but with new update SDK (PGSDK_VERSION @"2.7") is showing that parameters are missing:

```
func Pay_btn_Action(_ sender:UIButton!) {

    var orderDict = [String : AnyObject]()
    orderDict["MID"] = "WorldP64425807474247" as AnyObject
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP" as AnyObject
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail" as AnyObject
    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "worldpressplg" as AnyObject
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "100" as AnyObject
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = ViewController.generateOrderIDWithPrefix("") as AnyObject
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT" as AnyObject
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "1234567890" as AnyObject
    orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com" as AnyObject
    orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "8877877802" as AnyObject

    let order = PGOrder(params: orderDict)
    print(order ?? "nil")

    let transactionController = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionFor: order)
    transactionController? .serverType = eServerTypeStaging
    transactionController? .merchant = merchantConfig
    transactionController? .delegate = self
    self.showController(transactionController!)    
}
```

and it's going here:

```
func errorMisssingParameter(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, error: Error!) {
    print("Parameters")
    self.removeController(controller)
}
```

and I am using these urls:

```
merchantConfig?.checksumGenerationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp"

merchantConfig?.checksumValidationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
 orderDict["MID"] = "WorldP64425807474247"
        //Merchant configuration in the order object
        orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
        orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail"
        orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "worldpressplg"
        orderDict["THEME"] = "merchant"
        orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com"
        orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "8877877802"
        //Order configuration in the order object
        orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "100"
        orderDict["ORDER_ID"] =  ViewController.generateOrderIDWithPrefix("")
        orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "1234567890"


        let order: PGOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)
```